# How to extract information from .tmp file in DataStage

Tags: datastage

I have a list of tables, without delimiter but separate by wrap, in a .tmp file.

Is possibile extract one by one in DataStage?

Thanks

Comment: wrap = new line / line break? Can you give an example? Is it basically a table with a single column?

Comment: Hi Michael, wrap is new line, is a single column

Answer (score 0):

Ok so treat it as a file with a single column - new line is the row separator/row delimiter - this will result in a data stream with of multiple rows each with a single tablename.